# Make4ht and bclogo package compatibility

Tags: make4ht, bclogo

The following code produce a error :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\begin{document}
\begin{bclogo}{My title}
Test
\end{bclogo}
\end{document}
```

I compile with `make4ht file.tex`, i use texlive 2022 up to date (23/12/2022).

I have a error from Latex :

```
! LaTeX Error: File `bc-fleur' not found

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \begin{bclogo}{My title}
```

Comment: to get rid of the error, find bc-fleur.mps and run epstopdf on it to get a pdf and put it where latex can find it. But you will have to additionally configure the environment to actually use the flower in the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bclogo` doesn't have TeX4ht support yet, but it shouldn't be that hard to support it, if you want to convert it just as an picture. Try this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.svg,.jpg,.eps,.pdf,.mps}
\ConfigureEnv{bclogo}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

First thing it does is that it declares `.mps` as a supported image extension. It then requires conversion of the `bclogo` environment to a picture.

It doesn't work correctly though, because of a bug in TeX4ht support for the Mdframed package. You will need this version of `mdframed.4ht`:

```
% mdframed.4ht (2021-08-14-14:10), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2017-2021 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2021-08-14-14:10}


\NewConfigure{mdframed}{2}
\NewConfigure{mdframedstyle}{1}
\NewConfigure{mdframetitle}{2}
\newcount\mdf:env:cnt
\def\mdf:id{mdframed-\the\mdf:env:cnt}

\def\:tempa#1{\global\advance\mdf:env:cnt by1\relax\a:mdframed\a:mdframedstyle%
    \ifdefempty{\mdf@frametitle}{}{\mdfframedtitleenv{\mdf@frametitle}\a:mdframetitle\mdf@@frametitle@use\b:mdframetitle}\let\mdf@frametitle\@empty%
}
\HLet\mdf@trivlist\:tempa

\def\:tempa{{\b:mdframed}}
\HLet\endmdf@trivlist\:tempa
% 
% % disable frame drawing, it can be supported using CSS
\HLet\detected@mdf@put@frame\relax%
% 
\append:def\mdf@@ignorelastdescenders{\let\orig:unskip\unskip\def\unskip{\let\unskip\orig:unskip}}%
\HLet\mdf@lrbox\:gobble
\HLet\endmdf@lrbox\relax
\Hinput{mdframed}
\endinput
```

With these changes, you will get this result:

[image]

Comment: This new code don't work with amsthm : `! Package mdframed Error: mdframed detected package amsthm changed the theorem header of amsthm failed  (mdframed)`

Comment: @ManuelCart you are right. I've update the code to prevent `mdframed` from `amsthm` patching